# 'module' object is not callable - calling method in another file

Tags: python, import, module

I have a fair background in java, trying to learn python.  I'm running into a problem understanding how to access methods from other classes when they're in different files.  I keep getting module object is not callable.

I made a simple function to find the largest and smallest integer in a list in one file, and want to access those functions in another class in another file.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
class findTheRange():

    def findLargest(self, _list):
        candidate = _list[0]
        for i in _list:
            if i > candidate:
                candidate = i
        return candidate

    def findSmallest(self, _list):
        candidate = _list[0]
        for i in _list:
            if i < candidate:
                candidate = i
        return candidate
```

---

```
 import random
 import findTheRange

 class Driver():
      numberOne = random.randint(0, 100)
      numberTwo = random.randint(0,100)
      numberThree = random.randint(0,100)
      numberFour = random.randint(0,100)
      numberFive = random.randint(0,100)
      randomList = [numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, numberFour, numberFive]
      operator = findTheRange()
      largestInList = findTheRange.findLargest(operator, randomList)
      smallestInList = findTheRange.findSmallest(operator, randomList)
      print(largestInList, 'is the largest number in the list', smallestInList, 'is the                smallest number in the list' )
```

Comment: Python is not Java. None of this code has any reason to be in a class. Make them module-level functions.

Comment: In a more complicated python program, wouldn't i need all my methods organized in classes, I'm still thinking java, thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you will need some classes, but you will probably need plain functions too.

Comment: Happens a lot... A weird error when trying to implement Object Oriented Programming techniques

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The problem is in the `import` line. You are importing a *module*, not a class. Assuming your file is named `other_file.py` (unlike java, again, there is no such rule as "one class, one file"):

```
from other_file import findTheRange
```

if your file is named findTheRange too, following java's convenions, then you should write

```
from findTheRange import findTheRange
```

you can also import it just like you did with `random`:

```
import findTheRange
operator = findTheRange.findTheRange()
```

---

Some other comments:

a) @Daniel Roseman is right. You do not need classes here at all. Python encourages procedural programming (when it fits, of course)

b) You can build the list directly:

```
  randomList = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(5)]
```

c) You can call methods in the same way you do in java:

```
largestInList = operator.findLargest(randomList)
smallestInList = operator.findSmallest(randomList)
```

d) You can use built in function, and the huge python library:

```
largestInList = max(randomList)
smallestInList = min(randomList)
```

e) If you still want to use a class, and you don't need `self`, you can use `@staticmethod`:

```
class findTheRange():
    @staticmethod
    def findLargest(_list):
        #stuff...
```

Comment: Those two lines are identical to OP's code. The changed import fixes the error, but using OP's filename (and explaining the apparent redundancy) might help.

Comment: they are not *identical* - it is a dynamic call instead of a static one. (please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: and I don't *know* what the OP's filename is - I only guess it really is `findTheRange`, since that's the convention in Java. anyway, you are welcome to improve my answer.

Comment: You're right that the lines aren't identical, mea culpa. However, the *guess* that the module name is `findTheRange` is a very safe one (it's imported, it's used as if it was the class, as you note it's the Java convention).

Comment: It should be stated that imports are relative to the current file. I also would add clarification that `from <directory> import <file>` often becomes `from <pseudo_dir> import <file>` if dealing with a structure that mixes `Package`s and `Folder`s. PyCharm nicely denotes this in its "Project Explorer".

Answer (score 3):

- `from` a `directory_of_modules`, you can `import` a `specific_module.py`
- this `specific_module.py`, can contain a `Class` with `some_methods()` or just `functions()`
- from a `specific_module.py`, you can instantiate a `Class` or call `functions()`
- from this `Class`, you can execute `some_method()`

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from directory_of_modules import specific_module
instance = specific_module.DbConnect("username","password")
instance.login()
```

Excerpts from [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Modules should have short and all-lowercase names.
>
> **Notice:** Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.
>
> A Python module is simply a source file(*.py), which can expose:
>
> - **Class:** names using the "CapWords" convention.
> - **Function:** names in lowercase, words separated by underscores.
> - **Global Variables:** the conventions are about the same as those for Functions.

Comment: Can't you import the class from the specific module?