# Python error in script but works in jupyter notebook: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, calendar

I am getting the below error when running a script that creates a list of holidays in variable *h*. I first ran the script on jupyter notebook and it worked fine with no errors, however when I run it as a script it does not work.

I looked at several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780510/python-module-object-is-not-callable-calling-method-in-another-file) to resolve the issue, but I am specifying what I am importing in the script so not sure why it still does not work.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\user\config\workspace\ExcelProjects\src\root\nested\scrap.py", line 53, in <module>
h = USBankHolidayCal.holidays(datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 12, 31))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Code

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar, nearest_workday, MO, USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset, CDay
UKdays = []


class UKHoliday(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
rules = [
    Holiday('Boxing Day', month=12, day=26, year=2016,observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Christmas Day', month=12, day=27, year=2016,observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=2, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Good Friday', month=4, day=14, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Easter Monday', month=4, day=17, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Early May', month=5, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Spring Bank', month=5, day=29, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Summer Bank', month=8, day=28, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Christmas Day', month=12, day=25, observance=nearest_workday),
    Holiday('Boxing Day', month=12, day=26, observance=nearest_workday),
]
UKBankHolidayCal = UKHoliday()
h = UKBankHolidayCal.holidays(datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 12, 31))
for x in h:
    UKdays.append(x.date())
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: must depend on the way you import `datetime`.

Comment: you are terrific! that was it

Comment: my pleasure. I tend to avoid the `from` form as it confuses the editor (completion) and the humans :) I prefer the long forms with full namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do:

```
import datetime
datetime(2016, 1, 1)
```

you get

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

But if you do

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2016, 1, 1)
```

it works.

So the problem resides in the way you're importing `datetime`. You have to use the 2nd version in your case, or you're mixing up the module with the object, which share the same name.